# Salesforce & WordPress with Ninja Forms?

Tags: wordpress, salesforce, ninja-forms

Bit of a complicated questions, and I'm not sure where to start so thought I'd ask the community...

Basically, we've been using Ninja Forms on our WordPress website for a while. It works great in the fact that our enquiries are sent straight to SalesForce.

Now, I'd like users to be able to fill in a form on our WordPress site which will then push more complicated information through to Salesforce e.g. they could fill in details such as their medical history which would then be pushed through to Salesforce and held in their customer profile.

I'm not sure if Ninja Forms will be able to handle this though... how will it know where to put the information? Currently, our form submissions setup a new record. But instead of setting up a new record/customer, it would need to edit a currently setup customer, and fill their profile with information which they've submitted through the form.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this for start https://ninjaforms.com/integrate-salesforce-and-ninja-forms/ , and prior to use your custom objects your must read this https://ninjaforms.com/docs/salesforce-crm/ , this guide gives you the heads up on how to map the fields and how to use custom objects, of course this is mainly a salesforce work.